# Migration of EJB 2.1 from WebSphere to JBoss

Tags: jboss5.x, ejb-2.x

We have a application with EJB 2.1 running on WebSphere. Now we are migrating from WebSphere to Jboss 5.1.

Could you anybody help how to migrate my EJB 2.1 stuff from Websphere to JBoss?

I have ejb-jar.xml and I am not sure where to keep it. Do I need to have a separate project for EJB code? Now I have mixed EJB code with normal java project code.

Is JBoss.xml is mandatory for EJB 2.1 migration from WAS to JBoss 5.1?

Can I use the ejb-jar.xml as it is? If yes, could I know where can I keep those files?

I have configuration in web.xml as follows:

```
    <ejb-ref id="EjbRef_1161372912989">
    <description>
    </description>
    <ejb-ref-name>slatimer</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <home>com.test.ejb.timer.SLATimerHome</home>
    <remote>com.test.ejb.timer.SLATimer</remote>
    <ejb-link>ejbtest.jar#SLATimer</ejb-link>
</ejb-ref>
<ejb-ref id="EjbRef_1208534937303">
    <description>
    fdfds</description>
    <ejb-ref-name>tolreminder</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <home>com.test.ejb.timer.ReminderEmailTimerHome</home>
    <remote>com.test.ejb.timer.ReminderEmailTimer</remote>
    <ejb-link>ejbtest.jar#ReminderEmailTimer</ejb-link>
</ejb-ref>
```

Please help in this issue with detailed procedure.

Thanks